# Magento 2.1 SKU missing from order details

Tags: magento2

We have a  strange issue in that for only some products the SKU is not being carried through on to the order details. So when you look at the order in admin the SKU is missing. It is actually missing from the database within **sales_order_item** table.

I'm not even sure where to start looking in to this seen as it works for some products just fine. I've compared products and they look identicle as far as I can see.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is a screenshot of the admin - see how the SKU's are missing from 3 lines but not the top one...

[image]

Here is a screenshot of the database table - see how the SKU values are NULL...

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide a screnshot of the issue so we can understand more clearer

Comment: Hi, I have updated with screenshots thanks